# probability - factor of a number

Tags: probability

I have been struggling with the following problem. Can anyone help me with it? Thanks.

What is the probability that a randomly chosen factor of 15<sup>90</sup> is a multiple of 15<sup>65</sup> ? Express your answer as a common faction.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $15^{90}=3^{90}5^{90}$ is the prime decomposition of the number in question.

Any factor of $15^{90}$ then will be of the form $3^x5^y$ where $x$ and $y$ are integers $0\leq x\leq 90, 0\leq y\leq 90$

Any unique choice of $x$ and $y$ satisfying the above will be a unique factor of $15^{90}$.

How many factors of $15^{90}$ exist then?

> Pick the value of $x$, pick the value of $y$.  There are then $91^2$ possible factors.

A factor which is also a multiple of $15^{65}$ must have $65\leq x\leq 90$ and $65\leq y\leq 90$.

How many factors of $15^{90}$ exist which are multiples of $15^{65}$?

> pick the value of $x$, pick the value of $y$.  There are then $26^2$ possible factors.

**Assuming that each factor is equally likely to be picked**, we continue to find the probability by the number of factors which are multiples divided by the total number of factors.

> $\frac{26^2}{91^2}$